# Corrupt image file after uploading it using ftp command from linux, with type ASCII

Tags: linux, image, upload, ftp, ascii

I have try to transfer a image file using ftp command in linux, from linux platform to windows platform, doing like this:

```
ftp cs.unitbv.ro
ascii
get test.jpg
```

After this, when I open the image it says that the file is corrupted. If somebody know how to repair the image file let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to repair the file all you can do is ensure this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

transfer it as binary otherwise it will get corrupted as newlines are converted, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try transferring it using binary mode.